# Double square brackets and curly braces in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have had hard time to understand the syntax of the following SQL excerpt in PostgreSQL:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        dummy_view
    WHERE
        True
        [[AND {{UserId}}]]
        [[AND {{ObjectNo}}]]
        [[AND {{UserName}}]]
        [[AND {{ProjectId}}]]
        AND issue_date::DATE <= COALESCE([[{{EndDate}},]] to_timestamp('infinity')::DATE) -- (9999-12-31 11:59:59)
```

What does it mean the use of double square brackets and curly braces in where statement? In the last AND is using COALESCE with this strange syntax. As I understand, it compares if the issue_date is lower or equal to endDate or 9999-12-31 11:59:59 (if there is no endDate).

Comment: That's not valid SQL. It's most probably some kine of placeholder that is replace by some other tool.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name a tool that doesn't know about parameters, and resorts to catch-all tools instead of eliminating unwanted conditions

Comment: The entire `issue_date::DATE <= COALESCE([[{{EndDate}},]] to_timestamp('infinity')::DATE)` looks like an attempt to create a catch-all query for an optional `EndDate` value. Assuming `{{}}` are placeholders for values, a null EndDate results in `COALESE(NULL,'9999-12-31')`. That's less efficient than simply eliminating `and issue_Dat <= ...` because the database still needs to use the index. On top of that `issue_date::DATE` prevents the database from using any indexes that cover `issue_date` efficiently.

Comment: BTW: you can avoid the need for this construct by just defining `enddate DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT infinity`. (similar for timestamps) This will simplify all your queries.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/notation.html  brackets  indicate optional parts. I am not sure what double brackets mean.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on this, I wanted to confirm this was not Pure SQL even though did not find any documentation about double brackets. I found that this syntax is related to optional variables in Metabase based on this https://discourse.metabase.com/t/saving-native-query-questions-with-variables-for-use-with-dashboards/3349